# PowerBI: Club some values together without creating new column

Tags: powerbi

In PowerBI, I have some values in a column like R1, R2, R3, R4, R5 for each issue id. I want to use this data to plot a bar chart with 3 bars (R5 as High, R4 and R3 as Medium & R2 and R1 as Low) with each bar having respective count of issues. How can I do this without creating a new column or measure? If I have to use a new measure or column, what is the more efficient way of doing it?

NOTE: Number of rows is expected to cross 100K and data refresh is expected every 15 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to group the values (I'll call it `Level`), the simplest way is to put `Level` at `Axis` and put `ID` for `Value` and set the summarization to `Count`.

[image: no group]

If you have to group the values into some bins, you can add a new group for the `Level` column:

[image: new group]

[image: groups]

Then use the `Level (groups)` column as `Axis` instead of `Level`:

[image: Level (groups)]

Comment: Didn't know about the 'New Group' option. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks.